# Infinite number of points reflecting on the circle, must some two (or more) ever meet?

Tags: billiards

I just created a following problem.

Suppose that we have an infinite number of points on the circle and that they at the same time start to travel (all with the same speed) from the point where they are to some other point on a circle by folowing straight-line path and, when they arrive to some point on the circle they reflect by the law of reflection (as ray of light reflects on a horizontal glass) and so those points all reflect and follow straight-line paths and then reflect... and again and again...

Surely there are trivial and non-trivial directions of those points that result in that two or more points arrive at the same point either on or in the disk but my question is:

> Does there exist such initial conditions (points on the circle where that infinite number of points reside at time t=0 and infinite number of starting directions (one for each point)) so that we have that never are two or more points found at the same point in or on the disk?

I do not know much about infinite billiards so do not know is this already solved somewhere or well-known.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Take an irrational trajectory (one that is not periodic).  There should be a subset of points on the circle encountered by the trajectory such that starting from those at the same time should cause no collisions.  Gerhard "Haven't Run Into Proof Yet" Paseman, 2018.03.27.

Comment: If the chords are all the same length, then collision occurs only if two chords bisect each other, which does not happen.  Gerhard "Ran Into A Proof Finally" Paseman, 2018.03.27.